# Hoogle Git repository

Tags: git, haskell, hoogle, git-grep

Is there a way to use type signature searches on not just the current working set, but the entire history of a project?

The purpose would be to find and possibly recycle Haskell functions that were previously written and tested, but removed due to lack of use/need.

Comment: Hoogle though Git history? Very unlikely. Hoogling though previous _package versions_, much more feasible.

Comment: Hoogle can take text files saying which functions are available. There is no restriction on those names being unique, so if you generated a suitable input file, Hoogle could certainly be used.

Comment: @NeilMitchell So, thinking out loud here, a git hook that generated hoogle files off each new commit?  Would there need to be some way to dedup function sigs that haven't changed?  Or does hoogle handle that internally?

Comment: Yep, a git hook could work. You would have to manually dedupe signatures, as you'd need to give each one a complete link (including the git SHA1).