# How do you search across library versions in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, cabal, stackage, hoogle

How do you find out which version(s) of a particular library includes a given definition? In my case, I noticed that `gloss` fails to install with the GLFW backend...

```
Graphics\Gloss\Internals\Interface\Backend\GLFW.hs:12:45: error:
    Module `Graphics.UI.GLFW' does not export `WindowValue(..)'
cabal: Leaving directory 'C:\Users\Jonatan\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-
22520\gloss-1.11.1.1'
```

... so I'd like to find out when `WindowValue` was removed. I've tried Hoogle, Stackage and Hayoo, with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WindowValue` was last seen in [GLFW-b-0.1.0.5](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLFW-b-0.1.0.5).

I don't understand what is up with the version bounds in gloss, they somehow require GLFW-b ≥ 1.4.1, which makes no sense.

Comment: +1 For answering the second question. But is there a solution besides a manual search, or cloning the repo and using `git grep`?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any alternative method to suggest.

Comment: The general solution is to use the changelog, but unfortunately this package lacks one.

Comment: @NeilMitchell I'll be damned if it isn't the author of Hoogle. Any chance we could get support for this?

Comment: I suspect a solution would look very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45970886/hoogle-git-repository. It's a shame http://hdiff.luite.com/ doesn't provide something - if it diff'd just the module signatures that might give you what you want.